# add gdb target achitecture: aarch64

Tags: android, gdb, embedded-linux, arm64, gdbserver

I`m trying to debug android's Linux kernel. I can run gdbserver64 on the android device and connect to it with gdb on the host computer. However when i try to debug i receive this error:

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:2345
Remote debugging using localhost:2345
warning: while parsing target description (at line 11): Target description specified unknown architecture "aarch64"
warning: Could not load XML target description; ignoring
Remote register badly formatted:T051d:0000000000000000;1f:50f8ffff7f000000;20:641cf5b77f000000;thread:p57c.57c;core:5;
here: 00000000;1f:50f8ffff7f000000;20:641cf5b77f000000;thread:p57c.57c;core:5;
```

Its pretty clear that the host gdb does not have aarch64. Is there a way to add architectures to gdb? I cant seem to find a way to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to add architectures to gdb?

Yes: configure it with `--enable-targets=all`.

Comment: same issue; problem with this args whic is not recognized for gdb

Answer (score 0):

I had to build it from the [gdb source code](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/):

1. `cd gdb-10.1`
2. `./configure --target=aarch64-linux-android && make -j8 && sudo make install`
3. `aarch64-linux-android-gdb`
4. `set sysroot`
5. `target remote <android-ip-address>:<port-number>`